# Temporarily adjust font size?

Tags: fonts

I'm using Spacemacs, in term mode and on a mac. While I can adjust the standard font size I am often moving from/to a different monitor, and I want to be able to tweak the font size for the moment. Is there an easier way than changing the font size in my config file?

Comment: You can use the inbuilt `text-scale-adjust` command or apply one of the solutions mentioned here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7583/115

Comment: @KaushalModi I'm a beginner to this sort of editor. It looks like I need to define a function to use `text-scale-adjust`, or is there some way to use it out of the box?

Comment: In `emacs -Q` (without loading custom configs like spacemacs), `text-scale-adjust` is bound to `C-x C-=`. After hitting that, you simply hit `+`,`-`,`0` as you need.

Comment: Or you can find out if and what spacemacs binds that to by doing `C-h f text-scale-adjust` (*not sure if spacemacs binds `describe-function` to `C-h f` or something else*).

Comment: @KaushalModi Thanks for the `C-h f` tip, that's great. The documentation there confirms what you're saying, but those bindings aren't working for me.

Comment: Derp. `C` is `cmd` on a mac. Now they work. Thank you @KaushalModi

Answer (score 1):

On a mac it is `CMD +/-`.

To learn more about this, `ctrl h f` lets you learn about functions and their bindings. In this case `text-scale-adjust`, as described in other answers and blog posts. The docs say it is bound to `C-+`, but in this case, `C`is actually the command key, not the control key.

Comment: I don't use Mac but I have seen the same for, I think, any software out there.. Microsoft stuff, Adobe stuff, etc: *Ctrl (Win) <-> Cmd (Mac)*

Comment: @KaushalModi what's interesting is that looking up a method, `C-h f`, requires the control key. So it seems like maybe it means different things at different times on a mac?

Comment: That's definitely odd.. On unix-based systems and Windows at least, the `C-` means the exact same thing in `C-h f` and `C-x C-=`. To understand this better, I would first see in an `emacs -Q` session (without loading any config) if `C-` symbolizes.. is it consistently *Ctrl*, or consistently *Cmd*, or not consistent?

Comment: I hope a mac user weighs in to help you with this.